# How can i extract the values of a multipline string return type

Tags: javascript

I have got a function which will return three values .

```
function test(){
  var price = '10';
  var name = 'apple';
  var avialable = 'yes';
  var p = price+name+avialable; 
  return (p);
}
var test = test();
alert(test);
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/thkc0fpk/1/

please let em know how to do this , (return type can be changed also  if needed )

Comment: If you are concatenating a string and you know their structure, you can use any separator like a space or comma and then split the string based on that delimitter. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return an array instead:

```
function test(){
  var price = '10';
  var name = 'apple';
  var available = 'yes';
  var p = [price, name, available]; 
  return (p);
}

var test = test();
console.log(test[0]);  // price
```

or an object:

```
function test(){
  var price = '10';
  var name = 'apple';
  var available = 'yes';
  var p = { price: price, name: name, available: available }; 
  return (p);
}

var test = test();
console.log(test.price); // test.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply return an array?

```
function test(){
  var price = '10';
  var name = 'apple';
  var avialable = 'yes';
  var p = [];
  p.push(price);
  p.push(name);
  p.push(avialable); 
  return p;
}
var test = test();
```

Then you can have access to the string this way:

```
alert(test[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe an object could be returned here instead, like so:

```
function test(){
  var p = {
      price: '10',
      name: 'apple',
      available: 'yes'
  }; 
  return p;
}
var test = test();
console.log(test);
```

The object can be accessed by using `var price = test.price;` or similar.